# Query to insert 10 rows with a loop

Tags: postgresql, transactions

I'm trying to generate 10 rows with this query in PostgreSQL but it is not working. The first column is "zoneID" and the second is "accumulator". ZoneID has to be from 0 to 10, and accumulator stays as 0. Does someone know what is happening?

```
DECLARE @first AS INT
SET @first = 1
DECLARE @step AS INT
SET @step = 1
DECLARE @last AS INT
SET @last = 10

BEGIN TRANSACTION
WHILE(@first <= @last) BEGIN INSERT INTO classifier VALUES(@first) SET @first += @step 
END 
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: Where in the manual did you find this syntax? Especially the `@` usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement it without using loop. Try this:

```
INSERT INTO classifier (zoneID, crimeCounter)
SELECT x.zoneID, 0
  FROM generate_series(1,10) AS x(zoneID);
```

`accumulator stays as 0.` *I am assuming that you want to keep the value in accumulator column value as 0.*

Comment: Is not working. The Table is called "classifier" and I used to create the schema: create table classifier ( 
 zoneID SMALLINT,
    crimeCounter SMALLINT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    primary key (zoneID)
);

Comment: and I used this for the query: INSERT INTO classifier (zoneID, accumulator)
SELECT classifier.zoneID, 0
  FROM generate_series(1,10) AS classifer(zoneID);

Comment: @JoelCorporan:- Updated the answer. Try the query now!

Comment: @JoelCorporan:- What is the error message you are getting?